# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.MyApplication

Tags: android

I'm having a crash with an app published in Play Store that happens very infrequently (< 1%) and I cannot find the cause.

The app crashes at launch, and in Play Store console I have the crash logged with the following stack trace:

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.MyApplication
    at com.xxx.xxx.activities.BaseActivity.getApplicationComponent(BaseActivity.java:83)
    at com.xxx.xxx.views.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:65)
    at com.xxx.xxx.views.activities.startup.StartupActivity.onCreate(StartupActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    ... 9 more
```

The crashing method `getApplicationComponent` looks like this:

```
public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
    return ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent();
}
```

And the manifest references my custom application class:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

The app is installed in a few hundred thousand devices (same apk) and it works perfectly.

So far this only seems to happen on some Nexus 5X/6P devices running Nougat.

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone has any clue why this would happen only a few times?

**edit**

MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.applicationComponent = this.createApplicationComponentBuilder().build();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return this.applicationComponent;
    }

    protected DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder createApplicationComponentBuilder() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put MyApplication class code here?

Comment: Added the application class.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing a similar issue.

Comment: No. This only happened in a few devices and stopped happening.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on the variety of devices running Nougat, but not all users are affected. This crash occurs on certain condition which I cannot figure out.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, small selection of users all running Android 7.0, no pattern in the devices impacted.

Comment: Link to the AOSP ticket you created so others can star it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235272

Comment: I see this crash in play store too, only on Android 7.0 and 7.1 devices.